# Segmentation fault (core dumped) in C when assigning value to variable in struct

Tags: c

I'm getting this error when trying to modify an integer variable inside a struct.
This would be the struct:

```
typedef struct{
    tPartner *partnerList;
    int numPartners;
    tContract *contractList;
    int numContracts;
    tWorkspace workspaces[MAX_SPACES];
    int numSpaces;
} tCoworking;
```

And here is where I am trying to modify numContracts:

```
void add_contract(tCoworking *cw, int partnerID, int spaceID, int month, int year){
    int contractPosition;
    
    assert(cw!=NULL);
    assert(partnerID>0);
    assert(spaceID>0);
    assert(month>0);
    assert(year>0);

    if(checkReservation(*cw, month, year, spaceID)==true){
        printf("ERROR: Workspace %d is reserved in period %d/%d\n", spaceID, month, year);
    }
    else if(find_partner(*cw, partnerID)==NULL){
        printf("ERROR: Partner %d does not appear in the list of partners\n", partnerID);
    }
    else if (checksMaxAnnex(*cw, partnerID, month, year)==true){
        printf("ERROR: Partner %d has the maximum of annexes allowed in period %d/%d\n", partnerID,month, year);
    }
    else{
        if(cw->numContracts==0){
            cw->contractList=(tContract*)malloc(sizeof(tContract));
            //cw->contractList=(tContract*)realloc(cw->contractList, (cw->numContracts +1)*sizeof(tContract));
            cw->contractList[cw->numContracts].partnerID=partnerID;
            cw->contractList[cw->numContracts].month=month;
            cw->contractList[cw->numContracts].year=year;
            cw->contractList[cw->numContracts].annex[0].idWorkspace=spaceID;
            cw->contractList[cw->numContracts].annex[0].monthlyPrice=100000;
            cw->contractList[cw->numContracts].numAnnex=1;
            cw->numContracts=1;
        }
        else{
            contractPosition=findContract(*cw, partnerID, month, year);
            if(contractPosition==-1){
                
            }
        }
    }
    
}
```

To explain a little bit the code:

There is this struct tCoworking that has inside three lists: partners, contracts and spaces (like rooms for working that you can rent).

The action above tries to add a new contract and for that I first check if that space is already taken for that month, if the partner actually exist or not and if the partner trying to rent it has the max number of spaces rented that month (3).

I'm having this error trying to add a contract when the list of contracts is empty (numContracts==0). Once I add all the stuff (partner id, month, year, etc.) I have to do numContracs++ or numContracs=1  to keep a record of how many there are in the list. But I'm getting this error.

The variable has already been initialized here:

```
void init_coworking(tCoworking *cw){
    assert(cw!=NULL);
    cw->numPartners=0;
    cw->numContracts=0;
    cw->numSpaces=0;
}
```

I'm guessing is something about allocating memory but I'm very new to this and I really have no idea so any help would be much appreciated!

Thank you in advance!

EDIT:
I only shared the code I thought would be useful so you don't have to look through lines and lines of code but as it seems the problem is not there:
Here is the main function. It has been provided by the teacher and it shouln't have any mistakes:

```
#include "coworking.h"

/**************************************************************************/
  int main (void)
/**************************************************************************/
{
  tCoworking c;



  /* section a */
  init_coworking (&c);
  
  /* section b */
  printf("\n******************************************************************\n");
  printf("Section B:");
  printf("\n******************************************************************\n");

  new_partner (&c, 11, "Anwar Sherman", 10);
  new_partner (&c, 16, "Isa Warner", 20);
  new_partner (&c, 24, "Reagan Sawyer", 8);
  new_partner (&c, 67, "Hashir Lloyd", 10);
  new_partner (&c, 88, "Amaya Kaye", 10);
  new_partner (&c, 11, "Rio Griffiths", 25);
  new_partner (&c, 91, "Barney McFarlane", 0);
  new_partner (&c, 94, "Terry Burt", 8); 
  
  /* section c */
  printf("\n******************************************************************\n");
  printf("Section C:");
  printf("\n******************************************************************\n");
  new_workspace (&c, 1, 2.15, tableFlex);
  new_workspace (&c, 2, 2.10, tableFlex);
  new_workspace (&c, 3, 1.80, tableFlex);
  new_workspace (&c, 4, 2.05, tableFix);
  new_workspace (&c, 5, 2.05, tableFix);
  new_workspace (&c, 6, 6.25, officeFix);
  new_workspace (&c, 1, 8.00, officeFix);
  new_workspace (&c, 8, 8.00, officeFix);

  /* section d */
  printf("\n******************************************************************\n");
  printf("Section D:");
  printf("\n******************************************************************\n");
  add_contract (&c, 11, 1, 10, 2020);
  add_contract (&c, 11, 2, 10, 2020);
  add_contract (&c, 11, 5, 10, 2020); 
  add_contract (&c, 88, 4, 10, 2020); 
  add_contract (&c, 88, 1, 11, 2020); 
  add_contract (&c, 24, 8, 10, 2020); 
  add_contract (&c, 88, 1, 10, 2020); 
  add_contract (&c, 55, 6, 12, 2020); 
  add_contract (&c, 11, 3, 10, 2020); 
  
  /*section e */
  printf("\n******************************************************************\n");
  printf("Section E:");
  printf("\n******************************************************************\n");

  print_workspaces(c,10,2020);

  return 0;
}
```

This is the .c file that I wrote:

```
#include "coworking.h"

tPartner *find_partner(tCoworking cw, int id){
    tPartner *partner;
    int i=0;
    
    partner=NULL;
    while(i<cw.numPartners && partner==NULL){
        if(cw.partnerList[i].id==id){
            partner=&(cw.partnerList[i]);
        }
        i++;
    }
    
    return partner;
}

tWorkspace *find_workspace(tCoworking cw, int id){
    tWorkspace *workspace;
    int i=0;
    
    workspace=NULL;
    while(i<cw.numSpaces && workspace==NULL){
        if(cw.workspaces[i].id==id){
            workspace=&(cw.workspaces[i]);
        }
        i++;
    }
    
    return workspace;
}

//Checks if there is a reservation in a specific date and workspace
bool checkReservation(tCoworking cw, int month, int year, int id){
    int i=0;
    int j=0;
    bool reserved=false;
    
    if(cw.numContracts>0){
        while(i<cw.contractList && reserved==false){
            if(cw.contractList[i].month==month && cw.contractList[i].year==year){
                while(j<cw.contractList[i].numAnnex && reserved ==false){
                    if(cw.contractList[i].annex[j].idWorkspace==id){
                        reserved=true;
                    }
                    j++;
                }
            }
            i++;
        }
    }
    return reserved;
}

//Checks if the partner has reached the mas of 3 annexes in one month
bool checksMaxAnnex (tCoworking cw, int id, int month, int year){
    int i=0;
    bool maxReached = false;
    
    if(cw.numContracts>0){
        while(i<cw.numContracts){
            if(cw.contractList[i].partnerID == id && cw.contractList[i].month == month && cw.contractList[i].year == year && cw.contractList[i].numAnnex==MAX_ANNEX){
                    maxReached==true;
            }
        }
    }
    
    return maxReached;
}

//Finds the position of a contract in the list given a partner and a date
int findContract(tCoworking cw, int id, int month, int year){
    int i=0;
    int position=-1;
    bool found=false;
    
    if(cw.numContracts>0){
        while(i<cw.numContracts && found == false){
            if(cw.contractList[i].partnerID == id && cw.contractList[i].month == month && cw.contractList[i].year == year){
                found=true;
                position=i;
            }
            i++;
        }
    }
    
    return position;
}

void init_coworking(tCoworking *cw){
    assert(cw!=NULL);
    cw->numPartners=0;
    cw->numContracts=0;
    cw->numSpaces=0;
}

void new_partner(tCoworking *cw, int partnerID, char name[MAX_NAME], int discount){
    assert(cw!=NULL);
    assert(partnerID>0);
    assert(discount>=0);
    
    if (find_partner(*cw, partnerID)!=NULL){
        printf("ERROR: Partner %d is already in the list of partners\n", partnerID);
    }
    else{
        if(cw->numPartners ==0){
            cw->partnerList=(tPartner*)malloc(sizeof(tPartner));
        }
        else{
            cw->partnerList=(tPartner*)realloc(cw->partnerList, (cw->numPartners+1)*sizeof(tPartner));
        }
        cw->partnerList[cw->numPartners].id=partnerID;
        strcpy(cw->partnerList[cw->numPartners].name, name);
        cw->partnerList[cw->numPartners].discount=discount;
        cw->numPartners++;
    }
}

void new_workspace(tCoworking *cw, int spaceID, double area, tFare fare){
    assert(cw!=NULL);
    assert(spaceID>0);
    assert(area>0);
    assert(fare>=0);
    assert(fare<4);
    
    if(find_workspace(*cw, spaceID)!=NULL){
        printf("ERROR: Workspace %d is already in the list of workspaces\n", spaceID);
    }
    else{
        cw->workspaces[cw->numSpaces].id=spaceID;
        cw->workspaces[cw->numSpaces].area=area;
        cw->workspaces[cw->numSpaces].fare=fare;
        cw->numSpaces++;
    }
}

void add_contract(tCoworking *cw, int partnerID, int spaceID, int month, int year){
    int contractPosition;
    
    assert(cw!=NULL);
    assert(partnerID>0);
    assert(spaceID>0);
    assert(month>0);
    assert(year>0);

    if(checkReservation(*cw, month, year, spaceID)==true){
        printf("ERROR: Workspace %d is reserved in period %d/%d\n", spaceID, month, year);
    }
    else if(find_partner(*cw, partnerID)==NULL){
        printf("ERROR: Partner %d does not appear in the list of partners\n", partnerID);
    }
    else if (checksMaxAnnex(*cw, partnerID, month, year)==true){
        printf("ERROR: Partner %d has the maximum of annexes allowed in period %d/%d\n", partnerID,month, year);
    }
    else{
        if(cw->numContracts==0){
            cw->contractList=(tContract*)malloc(sizeof(tContract));
            //cw->contractList=(tContract*)realloc(cw->contractList, (cw->numContracts +1)*sizeof(tContract));
            cw->contractList[cw->numContracts].partnerID=partnerID;
            cw->contractList[cw->numContracts].month=month;
            cw->contractList[cw->numContracts].year=year;
            cw->contractList[cw->numContracts].annex[0].idWorkspace=spaceID;
            cw->contractList[cw->numContracts].annex[0].monthlyPrice=100000;
            cw->contractList[cw->numContracts].numAnnex=1;
            cw->numContracts++;
            //printf("numContracts: %d\n", cw->numContracts);
        }
        else{
            contractPosition=findContract(*cw, partnerID, month, year);
            if(contractPosition==-1){
                
            }
        }
    }
    
}

void print_workspaces(tCoworking cw, int month, int year){
    int k=0;
    bool partnerFound=false;
    string name;
        
    printf("Workspaces reserved in %d/%d\n", month, year);
    for(int i=0; i<cw.numContracts; i++){
        partnerFound=false;
        k=0;
        if(cw.contractList[i].month==month && cw.contractList[i].year == year){
            while(k<cw.numPartners && partnerFound==false){
                if(cw.contractList[i].partnerID==cw.partnerList[k].id){
                    partnerFound=true;
                    
                    strcpy(name,cw.partnerList[k].name);
                }
            }
            printf("%s\n", name);
            for(int j=0; j<cw.contractList[i].numAnnex;j++){
                printf("Workspace number %d\n", cw.contractList[i].annex[j].idWorkspace);
            }
        }
    }


/*  for(int i=0; i<cw.numContracts;i++){
        printf("%d\n", cw.contractList[i].partnerID);
    }*/
}
```

And here is the .h file I wrote:

```
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <assert.h>

#define MAX_NAME 100
#define MAX_ANNEX 3
#define MAX_GENERAL 1000
#define MAX_SPACES 50
#define PTABLEFLEX 50.00
#define PTABLEFIX 80.00
#define POFFICEFIX 140.00

typedef char string[MAX_NAME];

typedef enum{
    tableFlex,
    tableFix,
    officeFix
} tFare;

typedef struct {
    int id;
    string name;
    int discount;
} tPartner;

typedef struct {
    int id;
    double area;
    tFare fare;
} tWorkspace;

typedef struct {
    int idWorkspace;
    double monthlyPrice;
} tContractAnnex;

typedef struct {
    int partnerID;
    int month;
    int year;
    tContractAnnex annex[MAX_ANNEX];
    int numAnnex;
} tContract;

typedef struct{
    tPartner *partnerList;
    int numPartners;
    tContract *contractList;
    int numContracts;
    tWorkspace workspaces[MAX_SPACES];
    int numSpaces;
} tCoworking;

tPartner *find_partner(tCoworking cw, int id);
tWorkspace *find_workspace(tCoworking cw, int id);
bool checkReservation(tCoworking cw, int month, int year, int id);
bool checksMaxAnnex (tCoworking cw, int id, int month, int year);
int findContract(tCoworking cw, int id, int month, int year);
void init_coworking(tCoworking *cw);
void new_partner(tCoworking *cw, int partnerID, char name[MAX_NAME], int discount);
void new_workspace(tCoworking *cw, int spaceID, double area, tFare fare);
void add_contract(tCoworking *cw, int partnerID, int spaceID, int month, int year);
void print_workspaces(tCoworking cw, int month, int year);
```

Comment: The bug is clearly in code you did not post.

Comment: it seems like you don't allocate memory to your struct pointers?
you need to malloc/calloc the struct pointer to be able to write to it.
btw for some reason it seems like you didn't even show where you declared that struct pointer and where you called the init_coworking function.
you should provide the relevant information so we will be able to answer it.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to an infinite loop in the while here:

```
bool checksMaxAnnex (tCoworking cw, int id, int month, int year)
```

The problem causing the segmentation fault was the condition in the first while. I was comparing an int with a pointer instead of comparing it with cw->numContracts

```
bool checkReservation(tCoworking cw, int month, int year, int id){
    int i=0;
    int j=0;
    bool reserved=false;
    
    if(cw.numContracts>0){
        while(i<cw.contractList && reserved==false){
            if(cw.contractList[i].month==month && cw.contractList[i].year==year){
                while(j<cw.contractList[i].numAnnex && reserved ==false){
                    if(cw.contractList[i].annex[j].idWorkspace==id){
                        reserved=true;
                    }
                    j++;
                }
            }
            i++;
        }
    }
    return reserved;
}
```